# Is it possible to re-use a computed property by passing a parameter (Vuelidate)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuelidate

I'm using Vuelidate for a form that has multiple sections. Each of these sections has formData object and name. Nested inside each of these is a ZIP object to validate zip code with numerous validations....required, numeric, minlength, and maxlength. What I would like to do is have ONE computed property zipCodeValid() and use on both. As of now I have two different computed properties targeting each section which is not terrible but I would like to see ONE reused for a cleaner approach.

```
Zip validation:
 zip: {
            required,
            numeric,
            minLength: minLength(5),
            maxLength: maxLength(5),
          }




   computed: {
        sectionOneZipValid() {
          return (
            (this.$v.formData.secOne.zip.$dirty &&
              !this.$v.formData.secOne.zip.numeric) ||
            (this.$v.formData.secOne.zip.$dirty &&
              !this.$v.formData.secOne.zip.minLength) ||
            (this.$v.formData.secOne.zip.$dirty &&
              !this.$v.formData.secOne.zip.maxLength)
          )
        },
  sectionTwoZipValid() {
          return (
            (this.$v.formData.secTwo.zip.$dirty &&
              !this.$v.formData.secTwo.zip.numeric) ||
            (this.$v.formData.secTwo.zip.$dirty &&
              !this.$v.formData.secTwo.zip.minLength) ||
            (this.$v.formData.secTwo.zip.$dirty &&
              !this.$v.formData.secTwo.zip.maxLength)
          )
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can pass an argument like this..

```
computed: {
        sectionZipValid() {
          return sec => {  return (
            (this.$v.formData[sec].zip.$dirty &&
              !this.$v.formData[sec].zip.numeric) ||
            (this.$v.formData[sec].zip.$dirty &&
              !this.$v.formData[sec].zip.minLength) ||
            (this.$v.formData[sec].zip.$dirty &&
              !this.$v.formData[sec].zip.maxLength)
          )}
        },
    }
```

and it can be called as

```
sectionZipValid('secOne') 

OR

sectionZipValid('secTwo')
```